# Realizar una comparación entre columnas whereRaw('columna1 = columna2 + columna3') a una colección

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy aprendiendo a programar con Laravel y tengo una colección de arrays que quiero dividir por atributos, en los cuales la suma de la segunda y tercera columna sean iguales a la primera, si aplico

```
$this->colección->whereRaw('columna1 = columna2 + columna3');
```

no funciona, pues me dice que el método no existe: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereRaw does not exist.   Sin embargo si lo hago desde el query builder, por ejemplo

```
Tabla::whereRaw('columna1 = columna2 + columna3');
```

jala de maravilla, no comprendo qué estoy haciendo mal, pues sí necesito aplicar el método a una colección previamente instanciada.

Comment: `$this->coleccion = Mipieza::where('venta_id', $sale)->get();`   donde $sale es una integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez que llamas al método `get` estás pasando de tener un query builder a tener una colección por eso no tenes acceso al `whereRaw`. Lo que tendrías que hacer es llamar al `get` después que armes la query entera.

Si por algún motivo no pudieras llamar al `whereRaw` antes del `get` lo que tendrías que hacer es filtrar la colección utilizando el método [reject](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-reject), tene en cuenta que va a ser más lento que la query ya que va a recorrer los resultados uno por uno.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora comprendo mejor cómo funciona